# How to Decode Html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

`enter code here`How to see Bold , italic etc text?

I have this in my view:  `@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Content))`

In my cotroller this :

```
 Content = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(opininonmodel.Content),
```

In index View where result should show I have this :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
}
```

i try with `Server.HtmlDecode` , but still see html tags not what they made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Html.Raw` helper which will not HTML encode the output like the `Html.DisplayFor` helper:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Raw(item.Content)
}
```